# 1) Displaying Text between Certain Times 2) Adding a "Time Recieved" Field on a Form

Tags: php, datetime, time

2 PHP related questions here I think:

1) Is it possible to use PHP to display a line of text between certain times, so for example, I might want to display   "Good Morning" between 5am and 12pm PST, "Good Afternoon" between 12:01pm and 4:59pm PST, "Good Evening" between "5:00pm and 9:00pm" and "Good Night" from 9:00pm until 4:59am PST.

If this is possible, what would the PHP look like?

2) I have a simple HTML form that posts its result into a database table.  Is it possible to add a hidden field somewhere that notes the DATE and TIME the data entry was added to the database?  If so, what would I add to my form and database?

Comment: This is not a forum. Each post is a question. Please post one question for each question. Also please do not tag titles or write thanks.

Comment: So sorry!  Was just trying to save space.  Isn't it polite to say Thanks?

Comment: Yes, but this is not a forum or chat; it is a knowledge resource. The question body should just contain the question. Anything else is just unneccessary noise, like this conversation. :) (And, arguably, when every single thing posted on this site is, by definition, a question and/or request for help, "thanks" are utterly redundant.)

Comment: OK Noted.  Sorry for the unnessesary fluff and Thanks for educating me :-)

Comment: No problem, and thanks for participating!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use an if-else statement to display certain text.

```
$current_hour = intval(date('H'));

if ( $current_hour < 12 )
{
    echo "Good Morning";
}
else if ( $current_hour < 17 )
{
    echo "Good Afternoon";
}
else
{
    echo "Good evening";
}
```

As for the HTML form, you'd be better off not having a hidden field, rather including the date from the page that processes the SQL statement.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php will help you format the date. Just format the date how you want it, and then include it in the SQL query.

Comment: Is this tied to the timezone on the clients computer, the server, or can I set the timezone?

Comment: PHP is server side, so it will be based on the timezone on the server. Your best bet is to either try to detect the users location based on IP address and change the offset (harder) or use JavaScript (easier). See http://www.onlineaspect.com/2007/06/08/auto-detect-a-time-zone-with-javascript/ for instructions for the JavaScript method.